# Custom function for search form

Tags: functions, search

I have the current function in my theme in order to alter Wordpress current search form:

```
function clarity_wpsearch($form) {
$form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:', 'claritytheme') . '</label>
<input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Search the Site...','claritytheme').'" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
</form>';
return $form;
```

}

However, I would like to change the submit input to an image. I found this code for reference:

```
 <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
```

However, I have tried to integrate this code inside my function without luck, maybe it's a PHP  issue I'm having, but I am having trouble figuring out.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to change submit input to image input? You can add image to submit button using background-image css property.

Comment: Exactly what fails about your code? Do you get errors? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bloginfo( 'template_url' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) will print the URL to the page and break the `return` of your function.

You need to use [`get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) to concatenate the result into the string.

```
function clarity_wpsearch($form) {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:', 'claritytheme') . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="'.esc_attr__('Search the Site...','claritytheme').'" />
    <input type="image" alt="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" src="'. get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) .'/images/search.png" />
    </form>';
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Hi @epilektric, this is exactly what I needed to figure out. I didn't knew how to write the proper PHP code in order to accomplish this.